# How to run multiple .asm files in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, assembly, masm, dosbox

I have just started learning assembly language programming in `x86` mainly using `DOSBox`. I was using DOSBox in a Linux virtual machine. Recently, I found an extension in vscode `MASM/TASM`:
[image]

So, I liked it and started using it since I could now write assembly language programs in vscode itself. But, the problem is it won't let me create another `.asm` file. Instead, it will just keep the single file I had created earlier. This file would always be there in the directory.
This is the one file (which I had created):[image]

And this is the file (and many others) which I want to add to the directory as well and use:[image]

This is the directory:
[image]

I have tried using `masm prac.asm`, but it gives a `does not exist` error. The only thing that works is `copy test.asm prac.asm` which addes `prac.asm` to the directory. On closing the dosbox emulator, the file `prac.asm` gets erased from the directory. Is there any way to  always have multiple files in the directory like `prac.asm`, `prac2.asm` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the settings for this extension there's one called `Working mode`. By default it's set to single file. If you change to workspace it will mount the whole dir.

[image]